# Remove .csv part from filename Jenkinsfile stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this Jenkinsfile and I am trying to remove .csv from filename using mv command but I am getting error when using following command.

```
stage("converting") {
            dir("users") {
               
                    files = findFiles(glob: '*.csv')
                    for(file in files)
                     {   println "CSV file is ${file} "
                           sh ("mv ${file} ${file/\.csv/}")    
                     }   
                    
            }
}
```

Comment: try changing order of params in mv command.
E.g. $ mv file.csv file

Comment: the first occurence already has .csv in the filename, second is trying to remove that part